# Android XmlPullParser returning null + attribute retrieve query

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

I am trying to do is parse a string which is in a XML format to retrieve certain values. Having looking at multiple XmlPullParser guides I believe the code should be correct, but it doesn't seem to properly look through the string and having run a toast message to see what event type was, it was returning null! 
Along with the correct way with looking through the string I wondered how I could retrieve the two values I wanted when the values are part of a start tag, and have commented where in the code I should do this.

Xml string looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><user-name>Bill</user-name><date>ISO 8601 format date</date><trk><name>Run One</name><trkseg><trkpt lat="47" lon="-122"><ele>5</ele><time>2007-10-21T11:23:29</time></trkpt></trkseg>
```

Here is the code:

```
 try {
            routeParse(routeInfo);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    public void routeParse(String routeInfo) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(routeInfo));      
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    // If tag is trkpt get attribute value lat and lon
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML parser returns null because your xml is not valid.
Check again what your input xml is.
If you have a typo in question, please update question. Also, paste your errors. Only in that case SO users can help you.

Comment: Sorry but could you help me understand why my XML is not valid?

Comment: '<trk>' is not ended in your XML. I highly recommend you to check your XML with a XML validator (you choose what validator you preffer).

Comment: Awesome I got the XML to parse after validating the XML, a lesson learned :) Any pointers to get the two attribute values from a tag?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see tag **trk** is not ended in your XML.